# Cannot retrieve picture from Ms Access to picture box

Tags: c#

```
cn.Open(); 
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select Photo Account WHERE UserName like Purchasedby", cn); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
da.Fill(ds); 
cn.Close(); 
byte[] content = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0]; 
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(content); 
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

it says that the Parameter is not valid>>
how should I do this??

Comment: Your SQL doesn't look valid to me.

Comment: it's an MS Access Database type..

Answer (score 2):

Please fix your SQL first. It should look something like this: `select Photo, Account WHERE UserName like '%Purchasedby%'`. If you still get error then provide the exception message and call stack if possible.

Comment: the Purchased by there is a row title just like UserNme and Photo

Comment: I think you have got the idea.